# Двоеточие или запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли поставлено двоеточие в предложении (можно подставить "так как") или лучше использовать скобки или даже запятую?

Преимущества и технологичность устройства заключаются в простоте установки, при его эксплуатации не требуется подтяжка, устройство можно использовать многократно без существенного износа: проведены испытания на пятикратное использование.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаемый вариант:

Преимущества и технологичность устройства заключаются в простоте установки: при его эксплуатации не требуется подтяжка, устройство можно использовать многократно без существенного износа (проведены испытания на пятикратное использование).

Comment: Со скобками согласна, но, мне кажется, двоеточие после "установки" не нужно, т.к. установка и эксплуатация - это разные вещи.

Comment: Мне показалось, что речь идет простоте монтажа, то есть не надо подтягивать монтажный крепеж, устройство можно легко демонтировать. Но если это не так, то двоеточие не нужно.